# Is there a function like PHP's array_merge() in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Does ActionScript3 have a function which can merge an array like in PHP?

```
array array_merge  ( array $array1  [, array $array2  [, array $...  ]] )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't one built in, or part of the standard library.

A keyless set of arrays would be combined with `array1.concat(array2);`

But the key based merging feature of `array_merge` isn't available. There's a set of Array utilities in the `as3corelib` https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib (there's a method called  `ArrayUtil.createuniqueCopy()` which might be what you want in there.)